# Execute external PHP script in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, external

Is it possible to run an external PHP script without needing to convert it into a plugin or using a controller?

My external code is only one file "index.php" which generates HTML code with PHP.

Can't I use it without modifying it on CakePHP 2.0?

What I want is to access to it like if it were a view, just like if I upload it on a normal site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can upload the external php file in the webroot folder of the cakephp

Comment: for example if you have a file "abc.php" you can place it in webroot and can access it as "http://yoursitepath/abc.php"